# Restrict phrases in form validation

Tags: php, validation

I have this setup to restrict what usernames people can have on my website. Is there anyway for it to pick up parts of words eg catch the word Administrator? or TheAdmin or IamAdmin

Thanks

```
$str = "administrator"
$os = array("admin", "mellwood");

if (in_array($str, $os)) {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'Sorry, that username is not allowed.');
            return FALSE;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

just use `strpos` to check like below

```
$str = "administrator"

$os = array("admin", "mellwood");

foreach($os as $name)
{
 if(strpos($name,$str)!==FALSE)
 {
  echo 'you cant use name containing admin';
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**stripos()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php). This will check if the `username` contains any of the restricted terms, regardless of the case - eg `Admin` or `admin` or `aDmIn` or `theAdmin` or `Theadmin` etc...

```
$str = 'administrator';

$os = array('admin', 'mellwood');

foreach ($os as $restricted)
    if (stripos($str, $restricted) !== false)
        echo 'username cannot contain the term ' . $restricted;
```